# save multiple uploaded files in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-file-upload

I want to upload and save multiple files in my application, I have
    `<input type="text" name="name" value="" />

     <input type="file" name="file" multiple/>`
   in my template. when I hit upload, seems  
`form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)` 
is only saving one file which is last in the list of the many uloaded files. How can I be able to save all the uploaded files using the form `form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES) blah blah`? Thanks

**Edit** 
`Myform` is a model form from this model.

```
class Docs(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    file = models.FileField(max_length=100, upload_to="documents/")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You maybe use `request.FILES['file']` or `request.FILE.get('file')` in MyFOrm. They only return a file.

Use [`request.FILE.getlist('file')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to get multiple files.

---

In your view:

```
....
form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    for f in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
        Docs.objects.create(name=name, file=f)
    return HttpResponse('OK')
...
```

Comment: Thanks @falsetru, How am going to save the files using the form?

Comment: @AlexKasina, As I commented in your question, it's hard to answer without `MyForm` code.

Comment: @AlexKasina, Define a method `save` (for example) that use `request.FILE.getlist` somehow. (I can only answer this way)

Comment: @AlexKasina, Do you want create multiple `Docs` objects to be created if multiple files are uploaded?

Comment: @AlexKasina, I added a code. I'm not sure how to do it with ModelForm. So I added non-form-aided code.

Comment: I had overridden the save method but I got an idea on how to do it now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The answer of @faksetru does not include save() method. So if you want to save your instace, it looks like this:

```
# in views.py
from .models import Docs
...
form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    for f in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
        instance = Docs(name=name, file=f)
        instance.save()
    return HttpResponse('OK')
```

For the more details refer to [official documentation of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model).

UPDATE:

I wrote a full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52016594/1375390), please check it out.