# How to access multiple files stored in a file field in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

We can save multiple files in one filefield, using `multiple` attribute in HTML input tag and using `request.FILES.getlist()` and `for` loop in views.
This works properly, but the question is:
When we save several files in one filefield of an object,‌ how can we access all of them in templates?
I tried the same as the code below but it did not work:

```
{% for foo in obj.filefield %}
    {{ foo }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can't store multiple files in the same `FileField`.

Comment: This post explains how to save multiple files in same filefield:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257231/how-can-i-upload-multiple-files-to-a-model-field

Comment: as the answer says, you define an extra model, where in the related model, the `FileField` each time stores *one* file.

Comment: so *no*, it is *not* saving it in the *same* filefield.

Comment: but all files are stored in the path of a file field of an object.

Comment: no, in the accepted answer, you have a `Feed` model, and a `FeedFile` model. The `FeedFile` links to the `Feed`, and each `FeedFile` carries *one* file. You thus simply construct *multiple* `FeedFile`s that each link to the same `Feed` if you want to store multiple files related to a `Feed` object. The same concept is repeated in the other answers, although with different names, and slightly different details.

Comment: If you want to upload multiple files using one form field... :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files

Comment: exactly, the form field can contain multiple files. But then in the view you see `...  # Do something with each file.`, this is where you thus construct the different `FeedFile` objects in the answer. The document thus makes abstraction about how you *process* the uploaded files, and you can not store multiple ones in the same `FileField` of the model.

Comment: A *form field* deals with handling user input, but it does not deal with storing it in a database record, that is what model field are dealing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can't* store multiple files in the same [**`FileField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField). You can only store one file. If you need to store multiple files, you make an extra model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …
    pass

class MyModelFile(models.Model):
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(
        MyModel,
        related_name='files'
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    file = models.FileField()
```

So for a `MyModel` object, you can add multiple `MyModelFile`s that then each store one file.

You can then render these like:

```
{% for file in obj.files.all %}
    {{ file.file }}
{ %endfor %}
```